# Excel отчет из SQL запроса

Tags: c#, sql, excel, служба

Существует RDL отчет, созданный в report builder, отчет генерят, выгружают в excel и отправляют на ряд руководителей предприятия. Отчет по сути голый SQL запрос просто аккуратно визуализирован в report builder. Вопрос, с помощью чего(возможно скрипт или батник), или как можно реализовать автоматическое создание готового excel файла с данными и автоматически отправить его на email? И что бы это все работало на планировщике или джобе. Я самоучка c# и php.

Comment: на php к примеру этим https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ можно сформировать xls а там если возникнут вопросу по конкретному коду пишите.

Comment: @Naumov тяжело будет поженить ms sql и php...

Comment: Почему это? http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-dblib.php можно и на c# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

По ключевым словам - report builder и rdl я предполагаю, что вы говорите о MS Reporting Services.

Если это так, то, загружая отчет на Reporting Server, вы прямо там можете настроить Sheduler для отправки отчетов на почту по определенному расписанию.

В качестве документации - классически - рекомендую MSDN:

https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms159762(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: спасибо большое, вы правильно поняли. Смогу ли я отправлять отчет сразу в excel или он просто ссылку на отчет отправляет?

Comment: Я не пользовался этим механизмом, но когда изучал его, вроде видел возможность отправлять сразу Excel в виде вложения. Посмотрите и попробуйте проверить.